# Echo variables in correct order

Tags: php, wordpress

**Set-up**

I've decided to try a little bit of PHP myself, I'm a total beginner.

I run a WooCommerce shop and want to dynamically display the expected delivery date range on each product page.

The delivery date range is today's date plus 3 and plus 4 days, e.g. today is the of 10th October so the delivery date range is 13 and 14 October. On each product page it should therefore mention,

`Delivery between Oct 13 and Oct 14`

I know where to write the code such that it displays where I want it to appear on the product pages.

I also know how to dynamically update the delivery dates.

---

**Problem**

Echo mixes the variables, instead of,

`Delivery between Oct 13 and Oct 14`

it states,

`Delivery between and Oct 13Oct 14`

---

**My Code**

```
function my_custom_action() { 

    $plus3 = strtotime("+3 day");
    $plus4 = strtotime("+4 day");   
    $date_low = date('M d', $plus3);
    $date_high = date('M d', $plus4);
    $start_text = _e('Delivery between ','woodmart');
    $end_text = _e(' and ','woodmart');

    echo $start_text, $date_low, $end_text, $date_high ;
};     
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 15 );
```

I need `$start_text` and `$end_text` in functions so the strings are translatable.

Preferably I also have the months (e.g. `Oct`) translatable, but for now I'd already be very happy to know how I get all variables echoed in the desired order.

Comment: _“Echo mixes the variables”_ - no, it doesn’t. `_e` directly outputs the translation, and _that_ is why you get the output in a different order than you expected here. You want to use `__`, not `_e`, if you want to assign the translated string to a variable.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -3):

This can be resolved using string interpolation.

for eg.

`$name = "PHP";
echo "I am reading {$name}POT";
// output: I am reading PHPPOT`

here's the link to a much more detailed reference : [variable-interpolation-in-php](https://phppot.com/php/variable-interpolation-in-php/)